# Выделение нескольких строк в 2ух datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать, чтобы выделяя несколько строк в 1ом datagridview во втором выделялись строки с теми же индексами?

Вот так вообщем нужно , чтобы выбирало те же по индексам грида строки справа, что и слева
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в 1 datagridview данные из access , во второй заносяться данные в результате вычислений

Comment: каждый из гридов привязан к таблице

Comment: через bindingsource